# how do i get nested form value to input to database table, instead of nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have a nested form in my rails app. The field that is nested is not adding values to the database.

I want an address added into my Places table. The address field is nested within a form that corresponds to the Post table.

I just pushed full code to github... http://goo.gl/wzjLK2

I think I am not doing something in my Posts Controller #CREATE

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @place = Place.new params[:address]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

For reference, my Posts form:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :upload %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :upload %>
  </div>

    <%= f.fields_for @post.place do |p| %>
       <div class="field">
        <%= p.label :address %><br>
        <%= p.text_field :address %>
      </div>

  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My Posts model...

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commenters, through: :comments, source: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :place

  def place_for_form
    collection = places.where(place_id: id)
    collection.any? ? collection : places.build
  end

end
```

Any help is so much appreciated. I've been stuck on this for two days now.

Answer (score 0):

After running the code, I notice there is an error in the server console:

```
Unpermitted parameters: place
```

After change this `@post.place` in

```
  <%= f.fields_for @post.place do |p| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= p.label :address %><br>
      <%= p.text_field :address %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

to `:place`, everything works fine.